# azure pyspark udf attribute nonetype after moving udf call into new function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I started with a working series of udfs like the one below to cleanse a list of columns in a dataframe that worked as expected.

1. populate dataframe
2. perform clean udf 1
3. ...

```
@f.udf(returnType=StringType())  
def ascii_ignore(x):
  return x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

def multi_remove_some_chars(col_names):
    def inner(df):
        for col_name in col_names:
            df = df.withColumn(
                col_name,
                ascii_ignore(col_name)
            )
        return df
    return inner

df = multi_remove_some_chars(colclean_list)(df)
```

My next step was to move closer to a class so I created a new function that calls all the data cleaning functions as shown below:  After the change the first function errors with " An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode''"  like the udf is not receiving the df and column list being passed???  Not sure I understand why this is happening.

```
def clean_names(sourceTable,sourceQuery,sourceId,sourceNameList):
  sourceQuery = sourceQuery +' ' +  sourceTable
  newTable = 'default.' + sourceTable + '_enhanced'  
  df = spark.sql(sourceQuery)

  colclean_list = []
  for col in sourceNameList:
    newname = col + "_m"
    df = df.withColumn(newname, f.lower(df[col]))
    colclean_list.append(newname)
  print(colclean_list)    
  df = multi_remove_some_chars(colclean_list)(df)
  df = multi_fix_abbreviations(colclean_list)(df) 
  #df = multi_remove_features(colclean_list)(df)   
  #df = multi_remove_stops(colclean_list)(df) 
  #df.write.option("mode","overwrite").save(newTable)
  #df.write.saveAsTable(newTable).mode("overwrite")
  df.show(500,False)

sourceTable='ndar_filtered'
sourceQuery='select NDARecID , FullName ,CorpOwnerName, OrgTypeCd from'
sourceId = 'NDARecID'
sourceNameList=['FullName','CorpOwnerName']
clean_names(sourceTable,sourceQuery,sourceId,sourceNameList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite likely that there are nulls in the column passed to the UDF. Try adding a check for null in the UDF:

```py
@f.udf(returnType=StringType())  
def ascii_ignore(x):
  if x is not None:
    return x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
  else:
    return None
```

In fact, a UDF might not be needed. You might get away with

```
df = df.withColumn(
    col_name,
    f.expr(f"replace(decode(encode({col_name}, 'ascii'), 'ascii'), '?', '')")
)
```

Comment: I had tried that but when I went to test the next more complex cleaning routines all written using this same pattern they all returned type errors after I moved the statement with the function call.  All of these functions worked fine when run sequentially.

Comment: @billSt3 you were just lucky that when you run them sequentially, there were no nulls. I'm afraid you need to change each of the UDF in your cleaning routine to check for nulls.